# pdfchecker: command not found

Tags: pdf, ubuntu-16.04, command-line-tool

can anyone help me to setup datalogics pdf checker in ubuntu 16.04 OS?
I have tried to setup as per their setup guideline but I am getting command no found error while trying to access executable file from terminal.

we are using this URL to download PDF checker.
https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdftools/pdf-checker/

we are trying to execute following command from our local system after setup.
https://dev.datalogics.com/pdf-checker/command-syntax/

Hoping to get help soon.
Thanking you in advance.

Ravi.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually run the program because I don't trust it. But I was able to extract the files, which should help you run the program. After you download the file, run the following commands:

```
unzip PDF-CHECKER-Lin64.zip
cd PDF-CHECKER-Lin64
ARCHIVE=`awk '/^__ARCHIVE_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' PDF_Checker1.4.0_Linux64.bsx`
tail -q -n+$ARCHIVE PDF_Checker1.4.0_Linux64.bsx > pdfchecker.tgz
tar xvfz pdfchecker.tgz
mkdir dist
cd dist
tar xvf ../PDFChecker.tar
```

This will create a bunch of files, including an executable named pdfchecker. To run from the current directory:

```
./pdfchecker
```

You should then be able to manually install these files wherever is convenient in your `PATH`. You may have to also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` where you install the library files.